# Change visibility of one itemscontrol via checkbox in another

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, visibility

I have two `ItemsControls` with the same `ItemsSource`. One has some controls for each item, the other has a `checkbox` for each item. The controls in them are dynamically added. How can I bind the `visibility` of the first `ItemsControls` to the corresponding `checkbox` in the other `ItemsControls` ?

Here's the first ItemsControl containing multiple `TextBlocks` in the row. Note: I want to hide the whole row of controls.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
               <TextBlock  />
               <TextBlock  />
               <TextBlock  />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here's the second `ItemsControl` with the `checkboxes`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                          IsChecked="True" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So what happens is, for each item in `VehicleCollection`, a new row of `textblocks` is added for the first `ItemsControl`, and a `checkbox` is added for the second `ItemsControl`. These should relate to each other for example: If I uncheck the first checkbox, the first row for the other `ItemsControl` should be hidden.

I know how to do the booltovis converter, just not sure on how to relate these two ItemsControls.

Edit: These are both in the mainwindow.xaml by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show or hide an item of the first ItemsControl, add an `IsVisible` property to your Vehicle class (i.e. the element type of the `VehicleCollection`) and bind the `Visibility` of the item's `ContentPresenter` to the `IsVisible` property in an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="{Binding IsVisible,
                            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the other ItemsControl, bind the `IsChecked` property of the CheckBox to the `IsVisible` property:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Of course make sure that class Vehicle implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fires the `PropertyChanged` event when the `IsVisible` property changes.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to manage this by adding a boolean Property in your `Vehicle` class, which I presume is the basis for your `VehicleCollection`.  Something like: `IsSelected`.

Then you can modify your XAML as shown below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <TextBlock  Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}"/>
           <TextBlock   Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}"/>
           <TextBlock   Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is untested XAML, as I just typed it into the answer.  Might need a tweak.